# convert varchar column to datetime mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: mysql

I want to convert a column name 'loan_date' i.e. varchar(100) to date time.
All dates in the column are like

```
01-10-12
22-12-12
31-01-12
20-10-12
```

I want all these varchar data to be in datet ime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function to convert varchar date into date time.

For MySql:

```
STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt)
```

[As seen here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4439776a21ec039cb058cbdf43c84cb9)